# Find all maximal ideals of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to find all maximal ideals of a ring

$R=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a & 0\\
b & a\\\end{array}\right),\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{10} \right\} $.

I assume that *matrix unit* are used here in order not to consider ideals that coincide with the entire ring (that is, ideals containing a identity matrix).
But the algorithm for finding the maximal ideals themselves is unclear for me.

Comment: Please include what you have tried in order to solve this problem. For example, have you been able to characterize the ideals or partially characterize them? This question currently has one close vote, if it gets to five it will become closed. For more information on asking good questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Start from the ground up such that what are the conditions for achieve the maximal ideals. Think about closure by addition and multiplication for the ring